# RDP through vpn from W10 to server 2008(r2) disconnects when idle

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, vpn, rdp, windows-10

We are having troubles with RDP-ing through VPN from two corporate owned  Windows 10 Pro laptops; the issue is that when there is no input on the established session, it freezes on client-side, and gets a “disconnected-state” on the remote desktop-server.  After performing user input on the frozen session, there is a reconnection-message on the client, and the same session gets reconnected.  It appears to be something related to the connection between the rdp-client software and the VPN-adapter, because the problem does not arise when a session is established when connected inside on-premises. 
I have already contacted Cisco for technical support, to rule out an issue with our VPN-device; an ASA-5508-x. After some tracing and testing the conclusion is: No drops on the ASA. 
When there is no input from the client device:
The client stops responding to retransmits from the remote desktop server, and the server resets the connection after 5 attempts accordingly.  (I raised the number of reconnects on the ts temporarily, and this improved the matter, but still did not stop the sessions from freezing sometimes)
**Noticable is the fact that, when the remote desktop session (mstsc windows) gets minimized, the connection will stay up.** 
**Also, when I perform an ongoing ping to an IP-address within the corporate network when a  rdp-session is established, the connection also stays up, even when maximized.**

Client machine: HP Probook 450 G1
VPN Device: ASA 5508-X
VPN: L2TP/IPSEC

I have performed the following tests / can confirm the following:

- Installed most recent os updates, no effect
- I have fully reinstalled the os, no effect
- Deinstallation of video driver (and disabled aut. installation of newer driver through Wupdate in gpedit,msc), no effect
- Installation of most recent video driver (and disabled aut. installation of newer driver through Wupdate in gpedit,msc) from manufacturer of laptop, no effect
- Installation of most recent video driver from manufacturer of video chip (and disabled aut. installation of newer driver through Wupdate in gpedit,msc), no effect
- I have uninstalled and recreated the vpn connection, and un/reinstalled all Wan Miniport drivers, no effect
- I have disabled power-saving on all network-adapters on affected client
- Set up Rd session active-idle settings through group policy (gpedit.msc) on client; this setting was only reflecting on sessions established to, not from  the affected client machine, no effect
- Disabled hardware-accelerated decoding through gpedit.msc on client, no effect
- Disabled UDP through gpedit.msc on client, no effect
- Set the color depth (within mstsc display-settings) to 15-bits (the same as setup on the ts), no effect
- Established the rdp-session within local administrator account on client, no effect
- The connection freezes when using any nic on the affected client; wlan, lan and mobile broadband
- The connection freezes when the affected client is connected through a mobile phone used as wifi-hotspot
- The connection freezes only when rdp-ing to Server 2008(r2) and Windows 7, rdp-connections to servers with older and newer os-releases are not affected
- The connection stays up when establishing a connection, and minimizing the mstsc.exe-window
- The connection stays up when establishing a connection, and performing a continuous ping to any IP-address within the same network the terminal server is residing.

I would appreciate some help with this strange issue

Comment: Do you have the "Configure keep-alive connection interval" set on the server?

Comment: @GregAskew; I tried that a while ago, bud did not conclude my findings back then. I will set it up as by Wilson Jia his instructions as seen on page: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/5d6cde46-a6b4-41c2-b87d-1d114de5c3d0/rdp-over-evdo-network?forum=winserverTS, and post back after testing. Thans for your reply.

Comment: @GregAskew; i have setup: 
"KeepAliveInterval"=dword:00000001
"KeepAliveEnable"=dword:00000001 on TS, in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server but i am not seeing keep-alive packets when performing a Wireshark-capture, and the session still gets diconnected. I will do some testing, to see if i can get some keep-alive packets going.

Comment: There was a defect in Windows Server 2008 R2 where the keep alive was not sent. It should be fixed if the KB3125574 and the latest security monthly quality update is installed. If they are, you may want to refer to the original KB article: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2647409

Comment: @GregAskew; Thanks for your reply, but the server is in fact a 2008 SP2 (not R2). However, I have deleted the manual registry-entries (that weren't making keep-alives from the RDS-server happening.), and have set the keep alive up through our Domain Group policies (Computer Conf\adm. templates\Windows comp.\Remote Desktop svc\Remote Desktop Sess. host\Connections\"configure keep-alive connection interval"), and set to 1 minute. I wil have to restart the server to see if this was effective. Policy is applied to the Server correctly, as seen in RSOP. I will keep you posted.